# Delphi Intraweb display form in panel - IWBootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, delphi, intraweb

I am planning on an application with IWBootstrap as I am very used to Delphi and would like to reuse a lot of code I've already developed. In desktop applications I use a special panel (part of the jedi tools) that can render the content of a form. This makes development very comfortable as the different modules can be created as individual forms and displayed in a panel on the main form on demand. This is much more comfortable than using frames (at least for me).

I would like to use the same technique with IWBootstrap but by now I have not found any way to accomplish that.

What I already tried is to use several panels (regions) with different contents and hiding-showing them. This has the disadvantage that all GUI elements of all panels are found in the page source also if they are not displayed. This increases loading time.

Comment: There's more in this world than IntraWeb to make a web-project and re-use Delphi code already developed. [There was a question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended) but was closed, sadly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Again I found the solution shortly after asking the question here:

https://github.com/kattunga/IWBootstrapFramework/wiki/6--Dinamically-create-and-destroy-controls-in-ajax-calls

Functinality can be created in a frame and displayed in the main region on demand.

This works like a charm!